# Send data within Child Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 3 Forms namely MainForm, Form1 and Form2. MainForm hosts Form1 in a `Panel`. On Clicking a `button` in MainForm, I am opening Form2 using `ShowDialog()` method. Now I have a `treeview` in `Form2`. **Now I want to pass the nodes selected in Form2 back to a `combobox` in Form1**. How can this be achieved? I have tried `Form1.Activate()` in Form2 but the code is not hitting `Activate` method in Form1.

Also I am using `Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(Me.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)` but I cannot see any items in ComboBox once Form2 is closed. What am I missing here?

Below is the code for better understanding.

`MainForm`

```
public Class MainForm

   private Sub OpenChildForm(childForm As Form)
       panelFormContainer.Controls.Add(childForm)
       childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
       childForm.Show()
   End Sub  
   
   private sub MainForm_OnLoad(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      
      'Adding child form to a Panel in Main Form
      OpenChildForm(new Form1())
   End Sub

   'Open Form 2 on Button Click
   private sub btnOpenForm3_Click(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm3.Click
       Form2.ShowDialog()
   End Sub 
End Class
```

`Form2 - Child Form Opened by button click in MainForm`

```
Public Class Form2

   'Click back button to go back to Main Form which is already having Form1 as child
   Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      Me.Close()
      Form1.Activate()
   End Sub

   'Click a Button to Add Selected Treeview node to Combo in Form1 
   Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) btnAdd.Click
      Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(Me.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
   End Sub

End Class
```

**Updated: I have updated the code but still not getting anything in ComboBox of Child Form1**

`MainForm`

```
Public Class Form1

Private currentChildForm As Form = Nothing
Private ownerForm As Form = Nothing
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OpenChildForm(New ChildForm1())

End Sub

Private Sub OpenChildForm(childForm As Form)
    If currentChildForm IsNot Nothing Then
        currentChildForm.Close()
    End If

    childForm.TopLevel = False
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    panelFormContainer.Controls.Clear()

    panelFormContainer.Controls.Add(childForm)

    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    childForm.BringToFront()
    childForm.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dialogForm As ChildForm2 = New ChildForm2()
    '
    Dim result = dialogForm.ShowDialog()
    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        AddHandler ChildForm2.Button1.Click, AddressOf ChildForm1.objForm2_Passvalue
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

`ChildForm1 which is hosted in MainForm`

```
Public Class ChildForm1
    Private Sub ChildForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If ComboBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ChildForm1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated

End Sub

Public Sub objForm2_Passvalue(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(PageDetail.PageTitle)
End Sub

End Class
```

`ChildForm2 -- Which is opened as Dialog`

```
Public Class ChildForm2

Private Sub ChildForm2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TreeView1.ExpandAll()
    Button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PageDetail.PageTitle = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

`PageDetail: Class used to get and set data`

```
Public NotInheritable Class PageDetail

    Private Shared pageTitleValue As String

    Public Shared Property PageTitle As String
        Get
            Return pageTitleValue
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            pageTitleValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

[image: Child Forms Demo]

Comment: There are quite a few ways you could do this, what works best is completely up to you.  Since your doing Form2.ShowDialog(), you could simply change the access modifier on TreeView1 so it's visible to MainForm in the btnOpenForm3_Click event.  You might also want to read up on default form instances.  Form1 & Form2, probably aren't the actually instances of the forms your looking for

Comment: What is `PageDetail.PageTitle`?

Comment: @user9938: it is just a class with property to set the data. Added that to the code as well.

Comment: I've added another solution that shows more ways to pass data between forms. Hopefully, one of them works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows multiple ways to pass data between forms. In the code below, I show how to retrieve data from a child form (ChildForm2) using a function, a property, or an event. This data is passed back to the parent form (MainForm). Once the parent form (MainForm) receives the data, it sends the data to a different child form (ChildForm1). Data can be sent from the parent form (MainForm) to the child form (ChildForm1) using one of the constructors, a method, or a property.

[image]

**Note**: `MainForm` is the startup form and is the parent to both `ChildForm1` and `ChildForm2` (ie: instances of both `ChildForm1` and `ChildForm2` are created in MainForm)

**Create a new project**

**VS 2019**:

- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- [image]
- Select **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

[image]

- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name
- Click **Create**

---

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

---

**Add Form** (Name: ChildForm1.vb)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>, select **Add**
- Select **Form (Windows Forms)...** (name: ChildForm1.vb)
- Add a `Label` (Text: "Select One")
- Add a `ComboBox` (Name: ComboBox1)

[image]

In Solution Explorer, right click **ChildForm1.vb**, and select **View Code**

**ChildForm1.vb**

```
Public Class ChildForm1

    Public WriteOnly Property PageTitle As String
        Set(value As String)
            'populate ComboBox
            PopulateComboBox(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Sub New(pageTitle As String)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        PopulateComboBox(pageTitle)

    End Sub

    Sub New(pageTitles As List(Of String))

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        PopulateComboBox(pageTitles)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub PopulateComboBox(pageTitle As String)
        'create new instance
        Dim pageTitles As New List(Of String)

        'add
        pageTitles.Add(pageTitle)

        'populate ComboBox
        PopulateComboBox(pageTitles)
    End Sub

    Public Sub PopulateComboBox(pageTitles As List(Of String))
        'remove existing data from ComboBox
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Text = String.Empty

        For Each pTitle In pageTitles
            'add 
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(pTitle)
        Next

        If ComboBox1.Items.Count = 1 Then
            'if only 1 item exists, select it
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Add a Form** (name: ChildForm2.vb)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>, select **Add**
- Select **Form (Windows Forms)...** (Name: ChildForm2.vb)
- Add a Label
- Add a **TreeView** (name: TreeView1)
- Add a **Button** (Name: btnAdd; Text: Add)
- Double-click "btnAdd" to add the Click event handler
- Add a **Button** (Name: btnCancel; Text: Cancel)
- Double-click "btnCancel" to add the Click event handler

[image]

In Solution Explorer, right click **ChildForm2.vb**, and select **View Code**

**ChildForm2.vb**

```
Public Delegate Sub PassValueHandler(ByVal strValue As String)

Public Class ChildForm2

    Public Event PassValue As PassValueHandler

    Public ReadOnly Property PageTitle
        Get
            Return TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PopulateTreeView()
        TreeView1.ExpandAll()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetPageTitle() As String
        Return PageTitle
    End Function

    Private Sub PopulateTreeView()
        'ToDo: Replace this method with code to populate your TreeView

        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

        'Parent 1
        Dim node1 As TreeNode = New TreeNode("Parent 1")
        Dim childNode1 As TreeNode = New TreeNode("Child Node 1")

        'add 
        node1.Nodes.Add(childNode1)

        'add 
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node1)

        'Parent 2
        Dim node2 As TreeNode = New TreeNode("Parent 2")
        Dim childNode2 As TreeNode = New TreeNode("Child Node 2")

        'add 
        node2.Nodes.Add(childNode2)

        'add 
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node2)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        'raise event
        RaiseEvent PassValue(TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)

        'set value
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

        'close
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        'set value
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel

        'close
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Rename Form1 to MainForm**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **Rename**
- Enter **MainForm.vb**
- When prompted "You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element 'Form1'? Click **Yes**
- In Properties Window, for "MainForm", set Text = "MainForm"

**MainForm**

- Add a panel to MainForm (Name: panelFormContainer)
- Add Button (Name: btnOpenChildForm2; Text: Open ChildForm2)
- Double-click "btnOpenChildForm2" to add the Click event handler

[image]

In Solution Explorer, right click **MainForm.vb**, and select **View Code**

In the code below, I've written it in such a way that it allows one to choose different options for both retrieving data from a child form, as well as, multiple options for sending data to a child form.

**MainForm.vb**

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private dialogForm As ChildForm2 = Nothing
    Private currentChildForm As Form = Nothing
    Private ownerForm As Form = Nothing

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'open Form
        OpenChildForm(New ChildForm1())
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenChildForm(ByRef childForm As Form)
        If currentChildForm IsNot Nothing Then
            currentChildForm.Dispose()
            currentChildForm = Nothing
        End If

        'set value
        currentChildForm = childForm

        'set properties
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        childForm.TopLevel = False
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None

        'remove existing controls
        panelFormContainer.Controls.Clear()

        'add
        panelFormContainer.Controls.Add(childForm)

        'show
        childForm.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateChildForm1ComboBox(pageTitle As String)
        If currentChildForm.GetType() = ChildForm1.GetType() Then
            'currentChildForm is an instance of ChildForm1

            'create reference
            Dim frm = CType(currentChildForm, ChildForm1)

            'option 1 - populate ComboBox by calling method
            frm.PopulateComboBox(pageTitle)

            'option 2 - populate ComboBox by setting property
            'frm.PageTitle = PageDetail.PageTitle
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOpenChildForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenChildForm2.Click
        'ToDo: Replace this method with code from Option 1, Option 2, or Option 3 below
                           ...

    End Sub

    Private Sub DialogForm_BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        'option 1 - get page title from property
        PageDetail.PageTitle = dialogForm.PageTitle

        'option 2 - get page title by calling function
        'PageDetail.PageTitle = dialogForm.GetPageTitle()

        'populate ComboBox
        PopulateChildForm1ComboBox(PageDetail.PageTitle)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DialogForm_PassValue(e As String)
        'set value
        PageDetail.PageTitle = e

        'populate ComboBox
        PopulateChildForm1ComboBox(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Choose one of the following options for retrieving data from ChildForm2. Replace the method `btnOpenChildForm2_Click` (in MainForm.vb) with the code listed below.

**Option 1** (DialogResult.OK)

```
Private Sub btnOpenChildForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenChildForm2.Click
    'create new instance
    dialogForm = New ChildForm2()

    'show dialog
    If dialogForm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PageDetail.PageTitle = dialogForm.PageTitle

        'populate ComboBox
        PopulateChildForm1ComboBox(PageDetail.PageTitle)
    End If

    'dispose
    dialogForm.Dispose()

    dialogForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note**: When using `Option 1`, the code for `DialogForm_BtnAdd_Click` and `DialogForm_PassValue` (in MainForm.vb) isn't used, so both of these methods can be removed.

**Option 2** (subscribe to btnAdd 'Click' event)

```
Private Sub btnOpenChildForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenChildForm2.Click
    'create new instance
    dialogForm = New ChildForm2()

    'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
    AddHandler dialogForm.btnAdd.Click, AddressOf DialogForm_BtnAdd_Click

    'show dialog
    dialogForm.ShowDialog()

    'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
    RemoveHandler dialogForm.btnAdd.Click, AddressOf DialogForm_BtnAdd_Click

    'dispose
    dialogForm.Dispose()

    dialogForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note**: When using `Option 2`, the code for `DialogForm_PassValue` (in MainForm.vb) isn't used, so method `DialogForm_PassValue` can be removed.

**Option 3** (subscribe to event 'PassValue')

```
Private Sub btnOpenChildForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenChildForm2.Click
    'create new instance
    dialogForm = New ChildForm2()

    'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
    AddHandler dialogForm.PassValue, AddressOf DialogForm_PassValue

    'show dialog
    dialogForm.ShowDialog()

    'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
    RemoveHandler dialogForm.PassValue, AddressOf DialogForm_PassValue

    'dispose
    dialogForm.Dispose()

    dialogForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note**: When using `Option 3`, the code for `DialogForm_BtnAdd_Click` (in MainForm.vb) isn't used, so method `DialogForm_BtnAdd_Click` can be removed.

---

**Here's a demo**:

[image]

**Resources**:

- [Form.ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)
- [Form.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)
- [How to populate a treeview from a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355670/how-to-populate-a-treeview-from-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: Dont know what mistake I did earlier. All 3 options are working perfectly. Thank you very much. May be casting the form using ``CType`` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than placing a `Form` on a panel, you might consider creating a `UserControl` and placing that on the panel. The following show how to pass data from a Form (Form2) that is shown using `ShowDialog()` to a UserControl (UserControl1) that exists on a different form (MainForm).

**Note**: `MainForm` is the startup form. If desired, the UserControl can be replaced with a Form.

**Create a new project**

**VS 2019**:

- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- [image]
- Select **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

  [image]
- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name
- Click **Create**

---

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

---

**Add UserControl** (Name: UserControl1.vb)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>, select **Add**
- Select **User Control (Windows Forms)...** (name: UserControl1.vb)
- Add a `Label` (Text: "Select One")
- Add a `ComboBox` (Name: ComboBox1)

  [image]

**UserControl1.vb**

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub PopulateComboBox(value As String)
        'remove existing data from ComboBox
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Text = String.Empty

        'add 
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(value)

        If ComboBox1.Items.Count = 1 Then
            'if only 1 item exists, select it
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note**: If using a `Form` instead of a `UserControl`, add the code for `PopulateComboBox` to your form.

---

**Add a Form** (name: Form2.vb)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>, select **Add**
- Select **Form (Windows Forms)...** (Name: Form2.vb)
- Add a Label
- Add a **TreeView** (name: TreeView1)
- Add a **Button** (Name: btnAdd; Text: Add)
- Double-click "btnAdd" to add the Click event handler
- Add a **Button** (Name: btnCancel; Text: Cancel)
- Double-click "btnCancel" to add the Click event handler

  [image]

In Solution Explorer, right click **Form2.vb**, and select **View Code**

**Form2.vb**

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PopulateTreeView()
    End Sub

    'ToDo: Replace this function with one that returns the desired data
    Public Function GetSelectedValue() As String
        Return TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text
    End Function

    Private Sub PopulateTreeView()

        'ToDo: Replace this code with your desired code to populate the TreeView

        'clear
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

        Dim topNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode("Computer")

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(topNode)

        Dim logicalDrives As String() = Directory.GetLogicalDrives()

        If logicalDrives IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each drive As String In logicalDrives
                Debug.WriteLine("drive: " & drive.ToString())

                Try
                    Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(drive)

                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(drive))

                Catch ex As Exception
                    'do nothing
                End Try
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        'in MainForm we'll subscribe to the Add button Click event and retrieve the data by calling function "GetSelectedValue", so all we have to do here is close the form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Rename Form1 to MainForm**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **Rename**
- Enter **MainForm.vb**
- When prompted "You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element 'Form1'? Click **Yes**
- In Properties Window, for "MainForm", set Text = "MainForm"

**Build Project**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>, select **Build**

**MainForm**

- Add a panel to MainForm (Name: panel1)
- In Toolbox (View => Toolbox), expand: <solution name> Components
- Drag **UserControl1** onto **panel1** on MainForm
- Add Button (Name: btnOpenForm2; Text: Open Form2)
- Double-click "btnOpenForm2" to add the Click event handler

  [image]

In Solution Explorer, right click **MainForm.vb**, and select **View Code**

**MainForm.vb**

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private frm2 As Form2 = Nothing

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOpenForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm2.Click
        If frm2 Is Nothing Then
            'create new instance
            frm2 = New Form2()
        End If

        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler frm2.btnAdd.Click, AddressOf Frm2BtnAdd_Click

        'show dialog 
        frm2.ShowDialog()

        'the code below will execute after frm2 is closed

        'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
        RemoveHandler frm2.btnAdd.Click, AddressOf Frm2BtnAdd_Click

        'dispose
        frm2.Dispose()

        frm2 = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Frm2BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        'call method to populate ComboBox
        'UserControl11.PopulateComboBox(frm2.GetSelectedValue())

        'call function to get data
        Dim userSelection As String = frm2.GetSelectedValue()

        'call method to populate ComboBox
        UserControl11.PopulateComboBox(userSelection)

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Here's a demonstration**:

[image]

**Resources**

- [How to populate a treeview from a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355670/how-to-populate-a-treeview-from-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer,but my requirement is, my combo box is not in 'MainForm' but in another Form within MainForm. In this Form I have some other controls other than just combo box. I am opening Form2 from MainForm but I want to populate combo in Form1 after Form2 is closed. How can this be achieved? Should I use 'AddHandler' and 'RemoveHandler' in the form where Combo is placed?

Comment: The `ComboBox` in the above code isn't in `MainForm` either-it's in `UserControl1` (where you can add your additional controls. If desired, in the above code, replace `UserControl1`  and the associated code, with `Form1`. I recommend that you create a new project and follow the above step-by-step, rather than just trying to read it.

Comment: Yes I am trying with your example. It is working with Usercontrol but not with Form. I have a Form with Combo and with lot of other controls as well. How to make it work with Form?

Comment: It looks like I forgot to post the code for "UserControl1.vb"-I've added it to the post.

Comment: In `Frm2BtnAdd_Click` (MainForm.vb), I split the statements up to make it make it easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry to say it ain't working. Cant see anything in ``ComboBox`` of ``Form1`` after ``Form2`` is closed.

Comment: Please add the updated code you're using to your post, as well as images. Add it after everything you originally posted.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question with the additional code.