# Total value not updating when I update VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

The user inputs what they want in the forms. For example, in the snacks the user wants 2 burgers and it will cost 160 each - which is shown in total value.

[image: This if the form, when I updating the value I want.]

Total value:

[image: This is the total value]

Then, the user changed their mind and decided they want 6 burgers instead of 2. The total value is still 160 when "Place Order" is clicked. I expect that the value will update when the user changes the input. How can I fix this?

(VB.NET)

```
Public Class Formpreceipt
    Dim party = Formrooms.txtparty.Text
    Dim partyy As Double
    Dim bday = Formrooms.txtbday.Text
    Dim bdayy As Double
    Dim vip = Formrooms.txtvip.Text
    Dim vipp As Double
    Dim deluxe = Formrooms.txtdeluxe.Text
    Dim deluxee As Double
    Dim fries = Formsnacks.txtfries.Text
    Dim friess As Double
    Dim burger = Formsnacks.txtburger.Text
    Dim burgerr As Double
    Dim cupcake = Formsnacks.txtcupcake.Text
    Dim cupcakee As Double
    Dim pizza = Formsnacks.txtpizza.Text
    Dim pizzaa As Double
    Dim icedtea = Formdrinks.txticedtea.Text
    Dim icedteaa As Double
    Dim soda = Formdrinks.txtsoda.Text
    Dim sodaa As Double
    Dim soju = Formdrinks.txtsoju.Text
    Dim sojuu As Double
    Dim beer = Formdrinks.txtbeer.Text
    Dim beerr As Double

    Private Sub Formpreceipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnplaceorder.Click
        partyy = party * 200
        bdayy = bday * 300
        vipp = vip * 400
        deluxee = deluxe * 500
        friess = fries * 40
        burgerr = Val(burger) * 80
        cupcakee = cupcake * 35
        pizzaa = pizza * 150
        icedteaa = icedtea * 20
        sodaa = soda * 35
        sojuu = soju * 80
        beerr = beer * 100

        txtotal.Text = "₱" & Format(partyy + bdayy + vipp + deluxee + friess + burgerr + cupcakee + pizzaa + icedteaa + sodaa + sojuu + beerr)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: All of your assignments should go in `Button1_Click`.

Comment: Is "Formrooms" a different Form?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711574/send-data-within-child-forms/69714303#69714303 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711574/send-data-within-child-forms/69743297#69743297

Comment: yes, the formrooms is a different form

Comment: Your form-level assignments like `Dim party = Formrooms.txtparty.Text` do not create an association between `party` and `Formrooms.txtparty.Text`.  Rather, they assign the contents of the textbox at the moment the form is instantiated, and then the variable stays that way until and unless you update it again.  This is the reason for suggesting that the assignments go into `Button1_Click`, so that the variables will get the updated text instead of just the text from when the form was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is room for improvement on your design, but as suggested by user9938, move the assignments to the Click() event of your button.

Change:

```
partyy = party * 200
bdayy =  bday * 300
vipp = vip * 400
deluxee = deluxe * 500
friess = fries * 40
burgerr = burger * 80
cupcakee = cupcake * 35
pizzaa = pizza * 150
icedteaa = icedtea * 20
sodaa = soda * 35
sojuu = soju * 80
beerr = beer * 100
```

To:

```
partyy = Formrooms.txtparty.Text * 200
bdayy = Formrooms.txtbday.Text * 300
vipp = Formrooms.txtvip.Text * 400
deluxee = Formrooms.txtdeluxe.Text * 500
friess = Formsnacks.txtfries.Text * 40
burgerr = Formsnacks.txtburger.Text * 80
cupcakee = Formsnacks.txtcupcake.Text * 35
pizzaa = Formsnacks.txtpizza.Text * 150
icedteaa = Formdrinks.txticedtea.Text * 20
sodaa = Formdrinks.txtsoda.Text * 35
sojuu = Formdrinks.txtsoju.Text * 80
beerr = Formdrinks.txtbeer.Text * 100
```

Comment: I'll try this thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code, in the `Button1_Click` you have `burgherr = burger * 80`
First of all I suggest you to get the Value of variable burger like `Val(burger) * 80`
after than, in your code I can't see where you update and use the total value... I expect that you have something like `TextBoxTotalValue.Text =  burgherr.ToString()`

Comment: Still having the same error bro

Comment: I expect that when the user updates the contents (e.g they enter 2 burgers and place order that is = 160. Then they will press the back button and change the quantity to 6. and then clicking the place order button again to change the total value but still display the same value