# How do I plot data from parent form in a child form? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child, eventtrigger

I have a parent form that holds an instance of a controller (Thorlabs KCube) which runs a set of motors.
The parent form also asks for the motors position every 300 ms.
Every time a new position is retrieved, an event is triggered that displays the updated motor position on the parent form. This  works fine

Now I made a child form that needs to get the motor position from the parent form and plot it in a spline curve. However, I'm having issues with transferring the position from parent to child.

What are the best ways to do this?
I have so far tried

1. this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(childForm.ShowPosition));
2. Delegate (in same name space) that points to the childForm.ShowPosition method + a public event for when the data is updated
3. Constructor in the child form that takes the motor position as input, then calls ShowPosition in the child form.

Neither works. The code compiles but the position is not plotted. I should mention that the same spline plot also plots other data generated in the child form and this works fine.

Here is how the position data is generated in the parent form. Please let me know how to get this to work in the child as well?

```
private void GetPosition(IGenericAdvancedMotor deviceX, IGenericAdvancedMotor deviceY, IGenericAdvancedMotor deviceZ)
{

    while (updatePosition)
    {
        Wait(300);
        try
        {
            StatusBase positionStatusX = deviceX.Status;
            positionX = positionStatusX.Position;

            StatusBase positionStatusY = deviceY.Status;
            positionY = positionStatusY.Position;

            StatusBase positionStatusZ = deviceZ.Status;
            positionZ = positionStatusZ.Position;

            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ShowPosition));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Wait(500);
        }
    }
}
```

ShowPosition in parent:

```
private void ShowPosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    posX = devices.deviceUnitConverterX.DeviceUnitToRoundedReal64(positionX,DeviceUnitConverter.UnitType.Length);
    posY = devices.deviceUnitConverterY.DeviceUnitToRoundedReal64(positionY, DeviceUnitConverter.UnitType.Length);
    posZ = devices.deviceUnitConverterZ.DeviceUnitToRoundedReal64(positionZ, DeviceUnitConverter.UnitType.Length);
    Lbl_posX.Text = posX.ToString() + " mm";
    Lbl_posY.Text = posY.ToString() + " mm";
    Lbl_posZ.Text = posZ.ToString() + " mm";
    
}
```

ShowPosition in child form:

```
public void ShowPosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(displayZ == true)
    {
        chart1.Series["Z stage"].Points.Add(posZ);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?force_isolation=true

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 . Although the code is in VB.NET, the beginning of the post may offer some useful information.

Comment: I think the problem is that I can't make a new instance of the parent form. If I do so, it doesn't keep the IGenericAdvancedMotor instances, therefore, the status objects are null.
Could be wrong though But the IGenericAdvancedMotor instances undergoes some changes with settings etc during the parent form. So a new parent form instance will just have null objects of the device?

Comment: Also, I want the graph to be changed whenever the status object changes. Not just when I initially open the graph.