# How to access form components from class modules in VB

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I am novice to the VB and I have a frame in a form which has YES and NO Radio buttons and text box. I am using Visual studio as my IDE and has multi forms. My requirements are as below,

1. If YES Button clicked and text box empty - display warning message upon clicking NEXT button
2. If YES or NO isn't selected - display warning message upon clicking NEXT button.

I have a customer.cls class in Class Module and trying to access the optYes.Value or optNo.Value for validating and displaying pop up message, but seems this ain't working. However I am able access under User Controls.

How can we access the form components in class modules?

```
Friend Function ValidateCustomer()
 If optYes.Value = Flase or optNo.Value = False (Not showing any list when .(dot) pressed)
    ValidateCustomer = False
    Call WhyPageInvalid.AddReason("Confirmation Must be Completed")
EndIf
End Function
```

In fact I can see the other existing components in the form(for example BirhtDate ) in the same routine are accessed as below,

```
Dim SetupCustomer As AbcISetupCustomer
If Not SetupCustomer Is Nothing Then
    If SetupCustomer.BirthDate <> "" Then
        ValidateCustomer = False
        Call WhyPageInvalid.AddReason(" Need Valid Brith date")
    EndIF
EndIf
```

I tired including my frame components (YES/NO) to the SetupCustomer interface which I did not figure out, how that can be achieved. I also noted that the "BirthDate" in the properties window at the top showing as "BirthDate aiLookupCache",

[image]

and my "optYes/optNo" button as,

[image]

Hope this helps to understand better.

Comment: First thing is to make up your mind if you are working with VBA (Excel, Word...); VB.Net (Visual Studio) or with vb6 (old IDE). Those are complete different things and you tagged them all

Comment: That's got to be vb.net not vb6 or vba if you're using the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

Comment: I am using MS VB 6.0

Comment: @user09938 I am looking on how to access form components from Class Modules, so not much helpful

Comment: Please don't use incorrect tags. If you're using VB 6, change the `VB.NET` tag to `VB6`.

Comment: You may re-consider your program design so that there isn't a need to access Form components within a module. In VB.NET, one would pass the information as a parameter. Ex: `Public Sub MyMethod(tb as TextBox)` which is illustrated in the first section of the previously referenced [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711574/send-data-within-child-forms/69743297#69743297). In the image, this falls under the term "Method".