# Pass Information between 2 Forms - VB.Net - Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 2 Forms in a Product Registration Project

The 1st form has 3 buttons: New | Consult | Change | - that call the 2nd Form where I have a Photo Button.

New Button:

```
Private Sub tsbNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbNew.Click
        Try
            Using frm As New frm2ndForm
                frm.txtPrdCod.Enabled = True
                frm.txtPrdCod.Text = ""
                frm.ShowDialog()
            End Using

            tsbRefresh.PerformClick()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Consult Button:

```
Private Sub tsbConsult_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbConsult.Click
        Try
            If DGProds.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Select one product")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Using frm As New frm2ndForm
                frm.txtPrdCod.Enabled = False

                frm.txtPrdCod.Text = DGProds.CurrentRow.Cells("prdCod").Value.ToString.Trim 'dr.Item("prdCod")
                frm.txtDes.Enabled = False
                frm.txtDesRed.Enabled = False
                
                frm.ShowDialog()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
End Sub
```

Change Button

```
Private Sub tsbChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbChange.Click
        Try
            If DGProds.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Select one product")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Using frm As New frm2ndForm
                frm.txtPrdCod.Enabled = False
                frm.txtPrdCod.Text = DGProds.CurrentRow.Cells("prdCod").Value.ToString.Trim 'dr.Item("prdCod")
                frm.ShowDialog()
            End Using

            tsbRefresh.PerformClick()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
End Sub
```

In the 2nd Form, the Photo button will have two different behaviors:

- when the user has clicked on the "New" button on Form 1, the code will open a search screen for the user to select an image in a folder on the Photos in server and show it in the picturebox1 in Form 2;
- when the user has clicked on the "Consult" or "Change" button on Form 1, the code will make a comparison between the prdCod field of the Products Table and the filename of the image in the Photos folder and, when found, will show the image in the picturebox1 in Form 2.

If the "clicked button" on form 1 is "New", do the commands below:

```
Private Sub btnPhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPhoto.Click        
        Using open As New OpenFileDialog With {
                .Title = "Select Photo",
                .FileName = "",
                .Filter = "Images PNG,JPEG,BMP,JPG|*.png;*.jpeg";*.bmp;*.jpg,
                .Multiselect = False}
            If open.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

If the "clicked button" on form 1 is "Consult or Change", execute the commands below:

```
Private Sub btnPhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPhoto.Click
        
        Dim IdProduto As String = prdCod   ***field Products Table that will be used for the search in the Photos folder

        If File.Exists("\\server\cmg\projects\Photos" & IdProduto) Then   ***Search the image from the Photos folder on the server
           PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("\\server\cmg\projects\Photos" & IdProduto)
        End If
    End Sub
```

How do I check which button was clicked on the 1st form to be able to perform the correct Private Sub on the 2nd form?

Comment: Create a property on your 2nd form and set it when you create an instance in your first form. Set the value to 1 for New and 2 for Consult/ Change. Then compare the value in the button click events of your 2nd form.

Comment: You have asked two unrelated questions. SO requires that you ask one specific question so that one specific answer can be provided. If you want to ask two questions, you need to post two separate questions. In each one, provide only the information relevant to that question. Anything relating to image searches is irrelevant to passing data between two forms.

Comment: @jmcilhinney your remark makes sense, I just corrected my question as per your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b Could you please post this answer so I can select it as correct in case it solves my problem?

Comment: Create an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/enum-statement) and [How to: Declare Enumerations (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/how-to-declare-enumerations). Then create a constructor that has a parameter with the enum data type.

Comment: @user09938 Ok, I'll check the links you sent, thanks.

Comment: The first part of the following post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

Answer (score 0):

It worked:

In the first form (`frmConsProd`), in the New Button code (`tsbNew_Click`), I include the parameter that will be sent to
the second form (`frmCadProd`):

```
Public Class frmConsProd

    Private Sub tsbNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbNew.Click
            Try
                Using frm As New frmCadProd("New")
                    frm.txtPrdCod.Enabled = True
                    frm.txtPrdCod.Text = ""
                    frm.ShowDialog()
                End Using

                tsbRefresh.PerformClick()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the second form (`frmCadProd`) I created a class variable (`_operation`) and the constructor (`Public Sub New`) to receive the sent parameter:

```
Public Class frmCadProd    

    Dim _operation As String
    
    Public Sub New(operation As String)
        InitializeComponente()
        Select Case operation.ToLower()
            Case "new"
                _operation = operation                                    
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid option!")
                Close()
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks to Messrs. @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, @jmcilhinney e @user09938, for the help.