# C# How to dynamically creating a form and passing some parameters

Tags: c#, forms

I'm dealing with an C# windows form application.

1. I know how to dynamically create and call a windows form.
2. I Know how to pass some parameters to a windows forms before calling them by Frm_Sample.show();

but I cant do these two together.

Why?

because when we have a normal windows form , we have access to Its form class and we are able to edit it but when we call it dynamically , we are not able.

As I know , If I want to pass some parameters to a windows form , before calling , I have to write some code like below inside my form class definition.

```
public string ReturnValue1 { get; set; }        
public string ReturnValue2 { get; set; }
```

but if I call my form dynamically , how di I do that . Imagine this is my form creating code ...

```
Form aForm = new Form();
aForm.show();
```

How can I define some parameters inside aForm and pass my values before calling.

Thank you .

I have tried to add some attribute or method to my form class dynamically but I was not successful.

Thank you .

Comment: Also , I want to know how can I dynamically add some method and attribute to my form class , I know that I can pass parameter by form constructors , but when I want to define some parameters and return themes value  to caller form , or define some method dynamically , what should I do ?

Comment: _I want to know how can I dynamically add some method and attribute to my form class_: Are you an AI such as _ChatGPT_? If not, then create your form prior to runtime, like normal developers do. What are you trying to achieve? Create a virus?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711574/send-data-within-child-forms/69743297#69743297

Comment: @user09938 building dynamic, CMS-driven sites/forms (along with CMS itself) is well known past time activity for developers (right after writing own logging frameworks). I don't think one needs to assume some sort of fanciness like AI when very old school mundane goal would suffice :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with those concepts - just learned `Hello World` last week. :)