# How to pass data from textbox in one form to combo box in another form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to pass data from the textbox [name] that is in supplierForm to combobox [supplier] that is in inventoryForm.
Right after adding new supplier [textbox] in supplierForm without reloading the project, it should immediately display in the combo box in an inventory form. I did that and it worked but then it's not working, it either works for one time then it doesn't show anymore. I don't know why it's happening the way it does.

Screenshot of where the data is supposed to show in inventoryform in highlighted combobox: [image: inventoryForm]

Screenshot of where the data is passed from in supplierfrom textbox where the user keys in the supplier name then it should pass down the data: [image: supplierForm]

This is my code:
I wrote the code in supplierform to pass data to inventory form:

```
  Private Sub updateSupplier()
    Dim sp As Supplier = New Supplier()
    sp.txtName.Text = ComboBox4.Text
    sp.Show()
End Sub

 Private Sub supplier_list()
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=golden_star"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select supplier from golden_star.supplier"

        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        ComboBox4.Items.Clear()

        While READER.Read()
            ComboBox4.Items.Add(READER("supplier"))
            updateSupplier()
        End While
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

And I added supplier_list() onto Form_Load

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

Comment: If you put the results of you query into something like a DataTable object and bind it to your combo box rather than adding items directly then you just need to update that data table when adding new suppliers.  Would also suggest you do some reading on DataAdapters which will make this even more elementary.