# C# Pass Value From User Input Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to System.Windows.Forms so please excuse a newbie question. I have created a simple user-input form with two text boxes and a button. The intent is that the user types a value into tbox_H and tbox_V, and those values are passed back to the code that initiated the form. The default values of both text boxes are “1”. I have confirmed that the values are changing with the user input at the TextChanged events, and that those values are still in place at the MouseClick event. However, only the default values are being passed.

```
namespace MyCommands
{
    partial class MyForm
    {
        //Windows Form Designer generated code
        //some other generated code omitted for brevity
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tbox_H;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tbox_V;

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.tbox_H = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tbox_V = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            // button1
            this.button1.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Text = "OK";
            this.button1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseClick);
            // tbox_H
            this.tbox_H.Name = "tbox_H";
            this.tbox_H.Text = "1";       //default value
            this.tbox_H.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbox_H_TextChanged);
            // tbox_V
            this.tbox_V.Name = "tbox_V";
            this.tbox_V.Text = "1"; //default value
            this.tbox_V.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbox_V_TextChanged);
            // Form
            this.AcceptButton = this.button1;
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(tbox_H);
            this.Controls.Add(tbox_V);
        }
    }
}


using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyCommands
{
    public partial class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tbox_H_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("At TextBox", tbox_H.Text);   //Confirmed value changes
        }

        private void tbox_V_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("At TextBox", tbox_V.Text);  //Confirmed value changes
        }


        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("At MouseClick", tbox_H.Text + ", " + tbox_V.Text); //Values confirmed
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}


namespace MyCommands
{
    public class MyCommand1
    {
        MyForm form1 = new MyForm();
        form1.ShowDialog();
       int var1 = Convert.ToInt32(form1.tbox_H.Text); //only default value passed
       int var2 = Convert.ToInt32(form1.tbox_H.Text); //only default value passed
    }
}
```

I suspect my declaration of the text boxes as Public may not be the best approach. What is best practice for passing a value from a user-input form? Your guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 - it's VB.NET, but the same principles apply.

Comment: Don't use `this.Close();` in `MyForm`. Change that to `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`. Then, as IVSoftware is showing in their example, you should be checking DialogResult back in the main form to see if it was actually the button click or if they cancelled the dialog with X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is good here:

> I suspect my declaration of the text boxes as Public may not be the best approach.

It is more correct to keep UI elements `private` and expose each necessary value as a `public property` after making sure the input is valid.

---

**Properties**

Objectives for the user-input form:

- Provide two integer values V and H
- Make sure the public information is always valid (even if the internal UI state is not).

*Subscribe to text changed and visible changed events. This can be done either in the Designer view or in the form constructor as shown here.*

```
public partial class UserInputForm : Form
{
    public UserInputForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxV.TextChanged += onAnyTextChanged;
        textBoxH.TextChanged += onAnyTextChanged;
        VisibleChanged += onVisibleChanged;
    }

    // The public properties are available whether
    // the form is currently visible or not.
    public int V { get; private set; } = 1;
    public int H { get; private set; } = 1;

    // Whenever the form is shown, refresh the text boxes
    // with the last VALID values for V and H
    private void onVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visible)
        {
            textBoxV.Text = V.ToString();
            textBoxH.Text = H.ToString();
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

**Text Changes**

Validate the form when changes are made to the UI. For example, this simple scheme looks at both textboxes any time the text changes in either one. If invalid text input is present, the `OK` button will be disabled.

[image: user form validation]

```
private void onAnyTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    bool isValid = true;
    if(int.TryParse(textBoxV.Text, out value))
    {
        V = value;
        textBoxV.BackColor= Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        isValid = false;
        textBoxV.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }
    if (int.TryParse(textBoxH.Text, out value))
    {
        H = value;
        textBoxV.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        isValid = false;
        textBoxV.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }
    // Enable or disable the OK button based on
    // valid integer values of both textboxes.
    buttonOk.Enabled = isValid;
}
```

---

**Main Form**

Chances are, you want the user-input form to "remember" its previous values every time it is shown. For this reason, the main form will declare the dialog as a member variable and will be able to retrieve the integer values for `_userInputForm.V` and `_userInputForm.H` after first making sure that the input operation has not been cancelled.

[image: main form]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    UserInputForm _userInputForm= new UserInputForm();
    private void buttonShowUserInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure the dialog hasn't been cancelled by [X]
        if(DialogResult.OK.Equals(_userInputForm.ShowDialog()))
        {
            richTextBox.Clear();
            richTextBox.SelectionColor= Color.Navy;
            richTextBox.AppendText($"V={_userInputForm.V}{Environment.NewLine}");
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            richTextBox.AppendText($"H={_userInputForm.H}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox.Clear();
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            richTextBox.AppendText($"CANCELLED{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you IVSoftware for the tutorial. Your edits did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, everything seems to be fine:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Name = "Form2";
        this.Text = "Form2";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tbox_H = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tbox_V = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        // button1
        this.button1.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Text = "OK";
        button1.Location = new Point(100, 100);//Missing in your code
        this.button1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseClick);
        // tbox_H
        this.tbox_H.Name = "tbox_H";
        this.tbox_H.Text = "1";       //default value
        this.tbox_H.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbox_H_TextChanged);
        // tbox_V
        this.tbox_V.Name = "tbox_V";
        this.tbox_V.Text = "1"; //default value
        tbox_V.Location = new Point(50, 50);//Missing in your code
        this.tbox_V.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbox_V_TextChanged);
        // Form
        this.AcceptButton = this.button1;
        this.Controls.Add(tbox_H);//Missing in your code
        this.Controls.Add(tbox_V);//Missing in your code
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    }
```

I just commented missing parts in your code.
There is no matter of decelerations.

And about best practices, You can learn about MVVM pattern which is used on WPF (Next Generations of windows forms) [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/mvvm-implementation-for-windows-forms/).
You can also create UserControls and encapsulate your form logic there. if its hard to learn about MVVM.

Windows form and his brother in law WebForm both suffer from maintenance issues.