# How to Share Code Between Multiple Pages and Classes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, code-behind

Forgive me if I'm doing this wrong according to forum's rules, but I wasn't sure how to. This is a revision of the question asked at the link below. There was a response there that was close to an answer, but not exactly. To explain through "comments" or "edits" would have been too much so I thought I'd do a new thread.

[How to Share Code Between Pages and Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717530/how-to-share-code-between-pages-and-classes)

Anyway the (revised) question.

I'm trying to share code between **multiple** Code Behind pages and **multiple** Classes that uses objects and methods of the Page class. Simple examples would be using the "response" and "session" objects. However, in my real example I'll be using other Page objects and methods (e.g. GridView, Panels, etc...).

I'd like to save common Page Object related code in **multiple** shared Classes and share the code between multiple Pages and Classes.

Example below based on leveraging Albert's suggestion in my previous (which almost worked... credit and thanks to him).

When using the below I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to call "Class2_Procedure" *from* "Class1".

**Example of Page**. Calling "Class1_Procedure" and "Class2_Procedure" works. Calling "Class1_Procedure_Calling_Class2_Procedure" does not work.

```
Partial Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim MyClass1 As New Class1(Me)
    Dim MyClass2 As New Class2(Me)

    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Write("Default Page > Page_Load</br>")
        MyClass1.Class1_Procedure()
        MyClass2.Class2_Procedure()
        MyClass1.Class1_Procedure_Calling_Class2_Procedure()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Class 1**.  The issue is when you call the "Class2_Procedure" *from* "Class1".

```
Public Class Class1
    Dim MyPage As Page

    Sub New(MePage As Page)
        MyPage = MePage
    End Sub

    Dim MyClass2 As New Class2(MyPage)

    Sub Class1_Procedure()
        MyPage.Response.Write("Class1 > Class1_Procedure</br>")
    End Sub

    Sub Class1_Procedure_Calling_Class2_Procedure()
        MyPage.Response.Write("Class1 > Class1_Procedure_Calling_Class2_Procedure</br>")
        MyClass2.Class2_Procedure()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Class 2**. The "Class2_Procedure" can be called from the main page, but the issue is when you call the "Class2_Procedure" *from* "Class1".

```
Public Class Class2
    Dim MyPage As Page

    Sub New(MePage As Page)
        MyPage = MePage
    End Sub

    Sub Class2_Procedure()
        MyPage.Response.Write("Class2 > Class2_Procedure</br>")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is this code:

```
Public Class Class1

    Dim MyPage As Page

    Sub New(MePage As Page)
        MyPage = MePage

    End Sub

    Dim MyClass2 As New Class2(MyPage)
```

first up, you probably want ALL of the global scoped variables in the same place. (at the top).

The 2nd issue, is when you create the instance of the Class 1, the public variables are initialized that THAT point in time.

So, on "new" event, all of those values are defaulted to their values - but MyPage THEN gets set in the new event. (that looks to be too late for the public Class2 to pick up mypage. (if you converted that to a getter/setter, I think it would thus work.

So, if you want to "setup" some public members (variables) in that class, you should to do that in the new event - especially in the case that a class you are creating is depending on OTHER values that are public (you can't  control the order here if you use "new").

Use of new keyword for any public remember in class1 is fine in 99% of cases is just fine, not a issue.

However WHEN that/those variables (in this case a class instance) are to ALSO use other members/variables?
Then you don't have much control here.

So, force the issue, and make sure then MyPage is "for sure" setup, and then you can with confidence create the new instance of class2, which also requires that Mypage reference.

So, you need to write it this way:

```
Dim MyPage As Page
Dim MyClass2 As Class2

Sub New(MePage As Page)

    MyPage = MePage
    MyClass2 = New Class2(MyPage)

End Sub

Sub Class1_Procedure()
    MyPage.Response.Write("Class1 > Class1_Procedure</br>")
  .etc. .etc...
```

In other words, "new" keyword looks to be triggering for Class2 before it picks up mypage. (or better said "can" pick up MyPage)

Comment: This worked. Once again thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create the code or the function in a module and then, in the form that you're working with imports the module or the class, usually it's windowsapplication.classname.

Comment: This seems to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a BasePage:

```
Public Class BasePage
    Inherits Page
    'Some code here
End Class
```

and inherit your code-behinds from `BasePage`. This way you will be able to use the very same code at multiple pages. You can apply this pattern for other classes as well.

Comment: I believe that is what I tried originally as shown in the first post I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717530/how-to-share-code-between-pages-and-classes

Comment: @ptownbro and how was this idea not fulfilling your expectations?

Comment: How would call procedures using the Page object that are in that Class? Example, add a procedure named "BasePage_Procedure()" to your "BasePage" class that includes "Response.Write("hello")". How would call "BasePage_Procedure()" from the code behind page for "Defatul.aspx"?

Comment: @ptownbro you could Inherit your class from `BasePage`. So, if you have a `Procedure` belonging to `BasePage` and you inherit(!) from `BasePage` a `Class`, then all instances of the `Class` inheriting from `BasePage` will have access to `BasePage_Procedure`. Hence, you implement `BasePage_Procedure` once and you make sure that every page you have `Inherits BasePage`, so they have access to the common procedures and functions you want.

Comment: Interesting. If I understood you, I think you are saying instead of, for example, Default.aspx inheriting the Page object, have it inherit the BasePage class instead. Then, have the BasePage class inherit the Page object as well as have the BasePage_Procedure(). If correct that works, but I'd have to put all my page related code in that one BasePage class because one one inherit is allowed. I want to organize my code in separate classes (e.g. one for GridView code, one for FormView code, one for gentleal controls code, etc...). I could not separate them with this method

Comment: @ptownbro your first few sentences are accurately reflecting the idea, but afterwards I think I need to address some ideas you presented. "but I'd have to put all my page related code in that one BasePage class because one one inherit is allowed." No. BaseClass would contain only the code that all your pages need. Nothing stops you from applying the pattern of C inherits B inherits A. (C being your concrete class, A being BasePage and B being something in-between). This way, if you have some code to repeat accross multiple classes, then you can inherit from B (you will know its ideal name)

Comment: @ptownbro and B would inherit from BasePage. This way, BasePage would contain only what's necessary for all your pages and you could apply further, smaller generalizations for subclasses and inherit your actual page classes from them. As about controls, you can inherit from `GridView` a `MyGridView` where you could make your changes. You can do something similar with `FormView`. Yet, I do not know yet the exact goal you have for controls, so let me know if this idea is not useful (in that case please also elaborate on your goals regarding the controls.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I'll need to work on this a bit more and appreciate all the help.

Comment: @ptownbro no worries. Let me know if you have questions.