# Why does opening a form from a dialogform closes the dialogform

Tags: vb.net

I have a dialogform (Form2) (from my mainform (Form1)) which I created. When working in that form, I want to open another (dialog)form (Form3).  (I tried both a dialogform and a normal form). When opening the other form it stops the dialogform, returning to my mainform. When the people have given info in the extra form, it needs to return to the open dialog form but it keeps closing it and I do not understand why that happens.

The fOrm 3 is opened in a normal way:

```
dim ff as new form3("input")
ff.show
```

After this show command, it starts closing form2... Anybody an idea (and h why this happens? And maybe how to solve it?

Comment: What is the value of the DialogResult property on the button clicked? It should be DialogResult.None otherwise...

Comment: Thanks Steve..!! I seem to have copied the button (was some time ago) but it had the OK status..... Doing another test with a normal form, I used again a copy of the same button.. Stupid me........ Thanks for getting me unstuck....:)

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

Comment: Hi User09938. Absolutely an interesting page but it would not have solved my issue.. I created a nice looking button which I copied instead of taking a new button.. Stupidly I copied the "OK" button.. I was looking at the dialog results of the other form but completely missed to think about the dialog result of this button.... And I copied that button again when running another test... Steve triggered me to look in every step to hte dialog result and that triggered me to look to the dialogresult setting of that specific button (and I hit myself for my head)....You learn every day....but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, as I did in the comments, The problem was that the starting button that I use dwas a copy of antoher button which had the "OK" property with OK as dialog result.....