# How to pass a control to a class

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Im working on a class. what I'm trying to do is pass a comboboxedt with a repositoryItemComboBox to a class.
This is the area in the main form to call the event GetAllMics

```
  public XtraForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyEvents.GetAllMics(MicComboBoxSelect); <== Here is where i call on the event class.
        }

Below is where i want to control the comboboxedit it sets on a bar manager "Bar3"
passing the repositoryItemComboBox to access the class.


 public class MyEvents
    {
        public static void GetAllMics(repositoryItemComboBox tempControl)
            
            //(RepositoryItemComboBox tempControl)
        {
            var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

            for (int i = 0; i <= WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
            {
                if (i != WaveIn.DeviceCount)
                {                    
                    tempControl.Items.Add (enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active)[i]);

                    tempControl.Items.Add("It Passed");
                }
            }
            enumerator.Dispose();

        }
        
    }
```

Thanks

John G.

I Want to pass a repositoryItemComboBox on the event class so i can access the control.

Comment: And its not working because... ?

Comment: On a side note, why can't you return the data you would need for the control?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 - the post is VB.NET, but the same principles apply to C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is the first part of the main XtraForm 

 public XtraForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

      MyEvents.GetAllMics(repositoryItemComboBox);
       //Just the code above 
    }

//Here is the second part below.

  public class MyEvents
{
    public static void GetAllMics(RepositoryItemComboBox tempControl)
    {
        var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
            {
 
  
tempControl.Items.Add(enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, 
DeviceState.Active)[i]);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        enumerator.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks all of you who look at ny question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).