# create event in parent from from child from contained within a panel of parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a parent form that launches child forms that are loaded into a panel on the parent form.  I want to have a status bar on the parent form that any child form loaded in that panel can update. Because the child form is contained within a panel of the parent form, if I create a status bar within that child it is not at the very bottom.  Thus the reason I want to create the event to update a status bar within the parent form.

One of the reasons I need an event in the parent form is that you must refresh the status bar for the message to instantly appear.  That,and it is just more secure.  Below is the creation of my child form within a panel.  How can I raise an event from the child form in the parent form that I can use to update the status bar which is still visible?

```
frm_Copydata frm_Copydata = new frm_Copydata();
frm_Copydata.TopLevel = false;
frm_Copydata.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frm_Copydata.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
pnl_FormHolder.Controls.Add(frm_Copydata);
cmb_SelectAction.SelectedIndex = -1;
frm_Copydata.Show();
```

Solution that worked below:
Class for event

```
public class cl_StatusEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    public string strStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Child form code

```
 public delegate void StatusChangedEventHandler(object source, cl_StatusEventArgs args);
 public event StatusChangedEventHandler StatusChanged;
 protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(string status)
 {
     if (StatusChanged != null)
     {
         StatusChanged(this, new cl_StatusEventArgs(){ strStatus = status });
     }
 }
// triggering the event latter in the code of the child form
 var strStatus = "Processing FITS Image files";
 OnStatusChanged(strStatus);
```

Parent form code:

```
private void OnStatusChanged(object source, cl_StatusEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event triggered from copydata form");

    lbl_sts_ParmentFormStatus.Text = e.strStatus;
    sts_ParmentFormStatusStrip.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 - it's VB.NET, but the same principles apply to C#.

Comment: I suggest that you read [this](https://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html), which is my explanation of defining and raising custom events.

Comment: Create on the childs form a custom event, for example `OnStatusChanged` and let the parent form subscribe on this event for each childform

Comment: I havew not walked away from this and have read all of the responses.  I am trying to impliment the sugestions, but am struggling.   First c# app, but I will get it.  Thank you everyone

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.  I ended up using a custome event as sugested by jmcilhinney and  GuidoG.  jmcilhinney , I read through your execelent post about events but still had to search more to figure it out.  Between your post and this video by Mosh, I got everything to work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQgwEsJISy0  Again, thank you everyone.  What I like about this.  There are going to be a number of more child forms that I want to do the same thing, and it will be easy to add them by doing things this way.