# Displaying Both Old and New Values from Form1 in Form2

Tags: c#

I have three windows form say form1 ,form2 and pin form.In form1 user have to input some values.There is save button in this page .By clicking on save button Pin form is opened in that we have enter the correct pin and by clicking on submit button form2 get opened.In Form2 the values that user entered in the form1 is displayed in the old values column.

And then the user go back to form1 and modify the values and click save button to come to form2. That modified values are displayed in new values column.

The problem is that when second time i modify the values in form1 and click save to go to form2,there i am getting old values of form1 but I want both old values and new values.

I want to display both Old and New Values  in Form2.

Comment: WinForms maybe? Show us your code that accomplishes all of this...

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 (it's VB.NET, but the same principles apply to C#).