c# winforms. Problem when storing and calling controls
So I have two forms, a parent form and a child form, and a custom control.
The parent form has an empty list of the custom controls and a button that calls the child form.
The child form has a button to add/remove a custom control to a TableLayoutPanel, a button to save the custom controls to the list in the parent form, and a button to call the saved controls to the TableLayoutPanel.
The custom control is a TableLayoutPanel with a single row of ComboBoxes and a TextBoxes.
What I wanted to do, is that whenever I click save in the child form, the controls are saved into the list in the parent form and closes the child form. When I call a new child form, the child form will then be able to populate its TableLayoutControl with the saved controls.
The problem I have encountered, is while the controls are indeed saved to the list, I run into the error of System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'uEligibilityCondition'.
The code is below:

private void SaveSessionConditions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        uCustomControl custom = 
            tableLayoutPanelConditions.GetControlFromPosition(0, i) as uCustomControl;

        parent.sessionConditions.Add(control);
    }
}

private void CallSessionConditions()
{           

    foreach (uCustomControl custom in parent.conditions)
    {       
        int row = tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount - 1;
        
        // the line with the error 
        tableLayoutPanelConditions.Controls.Add(custom, 0, row);


        tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount = tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount + 1;
        tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40F));
    }
}


The first iteration of the code I have a button to save, another to remove all conditions, and another load. This works. The ComboBox selection and TextBox values are stored and called correctly into the empty TableControlPanel of the child form.
However, once I got to implementing it, as in having the save button also close the child form after saving and then when opening a new child form, it shows the error I mentioned.
To go about fixing it, I modified the code by creating a new instance of a uCustomControl.
private void CallSessionConditions()
{           
    // I tried one with parent.conditions and one with a conditions list within the form itself

    foreach (uCustomControl custom in conditions)
    {

        uCustomControl newCustom = new uCustomControl();

        newCustom.comA = custom.comA;
        newCustom.comB = custom.comB;
        newCustom.texA = custom.texA;
        newCustom.texB = custom.texB;


        int row = tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount - 1;
        
        tableLayoutPanelConditions.Controls.Add(newCustom, 0, row);



        tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount = tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount + 1;
        tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40F));
    }
}

So after this, the amount of controls/rows is correct. However, none of ComboBox selected items and TextBox texts are correct. They either default to the first item or have an empty text field. I also checked the list in both parent and child, the list in parent and child both saved the ComboBoxes, but not the TextBox values, and even then the ComboBox selections were not assigning to newCustom.
To further clarify, the below is the getter and setter in uCustomControl
public string comA
{
    get { return comboBoxA.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
    set { comboBoxA.SelectedItem = value; }
}

public string comB
{
    get { return comB.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
    set { comboBoxB.SelectedItem = value; }
}

public string texA
{
    get { return textBoxA.Text; }
    set { textBoxA.Text = value; }
}

public string texB
{
    get { return textBoxB.Text; }
    set { textBoxB.Text = value; }
}



My further thoughts include making a custom method that takes in a control and use that to assign the proper values, but I am so far stuck on its implementation, and since I also don't really understand the problem I am currently facing and why it occurred, I would like to ask here so that I better understand my code.
Thank you for taking the time to read.
Update: I tried a solution and made a custom method below:
public void SetFromControlInput(uEligibilityCondition input)
{
    comboBoxA.SelectedItem = input.comboBoxA.SelectedItem;
    comboBoxB.SelectedItem = input.comboBoxB.SelectedItem;
    textBoxA.Text = input.textBoxA.Text;
    textBoxB.Text = input.textBoxB.Text;
}



and used this instead of assigning each property one by one
newCustom.SetFromControlInput(custom);

It kind of worked and solved the issue of the ComboBoxes not saving since now it seemed like the newCustom does reflect the ComboBox selections, but the problem still remains that the TextBoxes are empty, and also cannot be saved into the list prior as well.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 (it VB.NET, but the concepts also apply to C#).

Thanks for the reply and link. Fortunately, I already solved it. So instead of saving the custom control in the child form as is into the parent form, I simply created a new instance of the custom control with SetFromControlInput like I did for CallSessionConditions.

I managed to work out an answer. I don't know if this is the best practice but it worked for what I intended. The only adjustment to the code is below:
private void SaveSessionConditions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanelConditions.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        uCustomControl custom = 
            tableLayoutPanelConditions.GetControlFromPosition(0, i) as uCustomControl;

        // new code below

        uCustomControl newCustom = new uCustomControl();
        newCustom.SetFromControlInput(custom);

        parent.sessionConditions.Add(newCustom);
    }
}

I realized that my first edit allowed me to resolve the not being able to access disposed object error, with the only issue being that the values were not set properly, I decided to create a new instance of the control and set the values separately before saving.
So now, my app can retain the value of the control for the session as long as the parent form is opened, add them to a new child form.
