How to listen to an event in a separate class
I am new to C# and I have a question about event handlers and how to listen to one from another class. See the pseodo code below. I created two classes. I have one class that has an event, and one that needs to be updated by the event. I am currently subscribing to the event in main and then passing the data on to MyClass2. How do I need to code MyClass2 so it can listen directly to the event and I don't have to subscribe in main and pass on the data. Is this possible? A good idea? Or should I continue to do it the way I am? Thanks for you help in advance.
public class MyClass1
{
      public event EventHandler<DeviceEventArgs> StatusChange;

      protected override void OnStatusChange(DeviceEventArgs e)
      {
             StatusChange?.Invoke(this, e);
      }

}

public class MyClass2
{

      public void ListenToClass1Event()
      {

      }
      public void UpdateStatusChange()
      {

      }
}
void main
{
      MyClass1 a = new MyClass1();
      MyClass2 b = new MyClass2();

     //i already know I can do this
     a.StatusChange += StatusChangeEvent;

     *//is there a way to just listen to the event in another class
     // so I dont have to write code in main or another class
     ???? b.ListenToClass1Event = a.OnStatusChange ????*
}
private void StatusChangeEvent(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e)
{
    b.UpdateStatusChange();
}



I have been doing it the way I know how, I wanted to see if the second way is possible, and/or a good idea or practice.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425 (it's VB.NET, but the same concepts apply to C#).

You could pass a reference of MyClass1 to MyClass2 in the constructor, then the 2nd class can subscribe to the event:
public class MyClass2
{
    public MyClass2(MyClass1 a)
    {
        a.StatusChange += A_StatusChange;
    }

    private void A_StatusChange(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e)
    {
        // Listen To Class1 Event
    }
}

Initialize like this:
MyClass1 a = new MyClass1();
MyClass2 b = new MyClass2(a); // <== pass a to b

Now, the event can be handled in main and in MyClass2. When you Invoke the StatusChange event, both event handlers main.StatusChangeEvent and MyClass2.A_StatusChange for the object b will be called.

You are welcome. Also, since you are new to StackOverflow, I would like to inform you that you can upvote good answers (if you have enough points) and accept the answer that helped you the most by checking the tick mark next to the Answer. On this site an upvote or an accepted answer counts as a "thanks".
