How to pass information from a datagridview to a windows form in c#
I am trying to make Windows form system to open a new form with a DataGridview, so that i can choose someone in that datagridview and it fills up the information from the first form with the information chosen from the datagridview.
Ex

In that picture when i choose the button next to the textbox, below "paciente ID" it opens the second windows form with the datagridview, what i would like to know is how can i past the information of the datagridview into the blank textboxes (only the information of the row i choose).
Wish for any advice, if you can help i will love it.
i tried using a method that automatically chooses the information from a selected row in the datagridview, but it only works for the textboxes in the same form as the datagridview.

There is a very great deal of detail information missing.  That said, I'd simply pass the data  to the other form, perhaps in the constructor, perhaps via a method.  Too many missing details to be more help.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78466009/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

This can be done with an event.
In the form with the DataGridView, populate the DataGridView with data, subscribe to KeyDown event, when a row is selected, pass the row data to the main form.
Here the DataGridView is populated using a BindingList/BindingSource where the data is a list of Customer. You can also use a DataTable.
Class for populating the DataGridView
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateOnly BirthDay { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Gender? Gender { get; set; }
}

DataGridView form, note the event CustomerSelected which is used to pass a Customer in this case back to the main form when, in this case the user presses the enter key on a row.
public partial class CustomerSelectForm : Form
{
    private BindingList<Customer> _bindingList;
    private BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public delegate void OnSelectCustomer(Customer sender);
    public static event OnSelectCustomer? CustomerSelected;

    public CustomerSelectForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        _bindingList = new BindingList<Customer>(CustomersList());
        _bindingSource.DataSource = _bindingList;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;

        dataGridView1.KeyDown += DataGridView1_KeyDown;

    }

    private void DataGridView1_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData != Keys.Enter) return;

        var current = (Customer)_bindingSource.Current;
        CustomerSelected?.Invoke(current);

        Close();
    }
}

Main Form
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void selectCustomerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using var f = new CustomerSelectForm();
        CustomerSelectForm.CustomerSelected += CustomerSelected;
        f.ShowDialog();
        CustomerSelectForm.CustomerSelected -= CustomerSelected;
    }

    private void CustomerSelected(Customer sender)
    {
        // populate the textboxes
    }
}

Clicking a button, subscribe to the event CustomerSelected in the form with the DataGridView, show the form.
In CustomerSelected event above, use sender to populate TextBox and other controls as needed.
