VB.net Multiple ListBox Selected Items carried into to separate form
Not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible. My goal is for the user to select multiple items from a list box. which are file names and be able to plot the data that's in the files on a separate form. where it takes that file name and searches a path looking for that file name. Example being John selects files ABC.csv and 123.Csv he will then click a button that says plot and it plots a overlay of the data from the 2 files.
I have my list box with all my file names I have tried doing it with multiple listboxes with one selection and 1 listbox with multiple selections. I can Currently plot 1 file no problem and get the code to send 1 file across to the other form. The issue lies with sending multiple. Ultimetley I am needing to create a "New" list that contains the selected files. Then I could take that "New" list to send it over correct?
objFileName.StringPassFileName = ""
ObjFileName.StringPassFileName = LstBoxSpectrumFiles.SelectedItem.ToString 
ObjFileName.Show() 


The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

Why are you using the name objFileName? That implies that it refers to an object that contains a file name. That's misleading and far from as accurate as it could be. I hate Hungarian Notation in the first place but, if you're going to use it, use it properly. A form variable should have the prefix "frm" and you should preferably only use "obj" for variables of type Object. Because there are so many types in .NET, many people use "obj" for everything that isn't an intrinsic data type in VB, which makes it rather pointless altogether. Just use descriptive names and no prefixes.

@jmcilhinney let's bring back type characters! :D https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters

Presumably your StringPassFileName member is type String. You can change the type to support multiple Strings, so use String[] or IEnumerable(Of String) or something like that.
Firstly, I'd suggest that that name is terrible. It should almost certainly be FileName or, for multiple, FileNames. It should also be a property rather than a field, if that's not already the case, e.g.
Public Property FileNames As IEnumerable(Of String)

You could then set it like this:
objFileName.FileNames = LstBoxSpectrumFiles.SelectedItems.Cast(Of String)()

You can then use it like this:
If FileNames IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each fileName In FileNames
        Dim filePath = IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)

        'Use filePath here.
    Next
End If

That code will work for zero, one or more selected files.
Note that, with a bit of LINBQ, you can incorporate the creation of the path from the name into the loop statement:
If FileNames IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each filePath In FileNames.Select(Function(fileName) IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName))
        'Use filePath here.
    Next
End If

