Enable or disable a menu in a form from another form
I have an application developed in Visual Studio 2022 that works with forms. In this application, there is a main form, from which other forms can be opened. In this main form, there is an item in the top menu ("Selecao"), which must be activated or deactivated depending on which form was opened.
For example, when the "Expenses" form is opened, the menu must be activated (enabled).
When this secondary form is closed, the "Selecao" menu must be disabled. I can enable the menu, but I can’t disable it. I tried to make the main form's menu public in the TelaPrincipal.Designer.cs file:
public System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem M_Selecao;

This way, I could disable the menu in the main form when closing the secondary form, but I get an error:

An object reference is required for the method or property 'TelaPrincipal.M_Selecao'

I also don't know how to do it from the main form. Can anyone help me?

Use a Property or a Method. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

passing your parent(main) form's reference in the child form could do the job if you are making the menu item public however it won't be that great to pass an entire form object. Simply pass the reference of the control (menu item in this case) to the child form and then disable it. Or you can create a static class to perform any similar actions on any control of any form.

Though, I've given my comment on the question, I feel myself tempted to give an answer which gives you another way to achieve what you are expecting.
From what I am able to understand, you are trying to enable/disable the whole menu item rather than the sub menu items under it. Also, the menu item is already disabled and will be enabled once the form is shown.
In this case you can create a method like ShowExpensesForm() which will look like this:
private void ShowExpensesForm()
{
    ExpensesForm frm = new ExpensesForm();
    frm.Load += (sndr, args) => selacoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    frm.FormClosing += (sndr, args) => selacoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    frm.Show();
}

and then you can call it from where you want to show the expenses form like on a click of a button or click of any other menu item and so on.
Note that I've assumed that enabling and disabling the menu item is the only thing you want when the expenses form opens which is why I used an Inline Event. However, if you want to do much more than that, name your events properly and apply the logic within the scope of those defined events.
Good luck.

Abhinav. It worked fine. Thanks.

@Ismael shouldn't this be an answer considering the simplicity and less code? just sayinn :-9

You're right. I thought I could mark all answers that work. Now I fixed it.

Setup an event in each child form as follows.
public delegate void OnMenuEnable(bool sender);
public event OnMenuEnable? MenuEnable;

In the child form to enable.
MenuEnable?.Invoke(true);

Disable
MenuEnable?.Invoke(false);

After creating a instance of a child form, subscribe to the event below.
using (var form = new YourFormName())
{
    form.MenuEnable += OnMenuEnable;
    form.ShowDialog();
}


private void OnMenuEnable(bool sender)
{
    M_Selecao.Enabled = sender;
}

For each child form, subscribe to the same event OnMenuEnable.

Hi, Karen. in the second line you wrote, the "?" gives an error. It tells me to use C# 8.0, instead of C#7.3. But my VS is already up to date. What to do? Thanks.

public event OnMenuEnable MenuEnable; should work.

Ok, Karen. Now it worked. Thanks.
